# Android App сценарий: как реализовать

Tags: android-service, android, broadcast-receiver

Доброго времени суток!

Есть определенный Арр. В установках есть пункт: Service. Выбрав его можно изменять данные для этой службы. Там же можно запустить/остановить эту службу с ресивером. При выходе из приложения служба уже не работает. Добавил все что надо для запуска ресивера после boot.
Так как Broadcastreceiver пользуется данными (sharedpreferences file) самого Арр, то не сработало.
Хотелось бы осуществить след. сценарий:
Отдельная служба, постоянно работающая в памяти даже после boot, которая берет данные Арр. С основного Арр, где подготавливаются данные для службы, можно подключиться к службе, запустить/остановить ее (даже так, чтобы после boot не запускалась).

Если бы линк на существующий пример, то разобрался бы. А может кто предложит более оригинальное решение? Скажем, как-то отдельным модулем подгружать службу или еще что-то похлеще...

Благодарю за внимание. Буду рад любому отклику.
comerun

Comment: Все заработало.
Надо было в манифесте показать полный путь к классу MyService.
Спасибо за поддержку.

Answer (score 1):

У вас служба и App идут разными APK?  
Если да - то зачем? Если нет - то этой проблемы быть не должно:

> Так как Broadcastreceiver пользуется
> данными (sharedpreferences file)
> самого Арр, то не сработало.

BroadcastReceiver - единственный способ запуска чего-либо при старте системы.  
Итого: непонятно, чего вы хотите добиться. Думаю, надо выкладывать код.